# HttpClient adding API key on header

Tags: c#, httpclient

Good day! I am consuming an API that uses API Key. I am using

```
HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("APIKEY", Token);
```

but it seems like it returns an internal server error whenever I use this. However, if I try to use `HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("APIKey", Token);` it seems like the api isn't returning an internal server error. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Check the documentation to see whether the api expects the header `Authorization: APIKEY <your api key here>` or `APIKEY: <your api key here>`

Answer (score 2):

You will need to build a better understanding of the API you work with first.

First check:

1. When using `HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("APIKey", Token);` - does this return an expected response? There are cases in which a web server may return http status code 200 (or other code indicating success) and serve an error page at the same time.
2. If on pt. 1 you get a valid and expected response - then you will probably have to check whether the API really expects "Authorization" header or a header called "APIKey" - some APIs may not use the standard "Authorization" header but a custom one.

Comment: `var checkApiKeyExists = request.Headers.TryGetValues("apiKey", out lsHeaders);`apparently this is how the api gets the value of the api key

Comment: I also do not understand how Postman accepts the authorization headers with API key as the key and the value is the token. But it doesn't work with httpclient

Answer (score 0):

The `HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization` call sets the `Authentication` header value, while in the second case you set a header with `API key` name.

The authentication header is in the following format: `<scheme> <value>`, where scheme is the type of authentication you use (Basic, Bearer, etc).